# Include a Python script in my html code (using BlueGriffon or any other HTML editor)

Tags: python, html

I would like to create a webpage on my website including some python scripts for performance scripting. how and which editor can help me simply on that?

Thanks, 
Lx

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, but browsers will not execute python code embedded in HTML...

Comment: You mean something like Brython?  http://www.brython.info/

Answer (score 3):

No browser recognizes Python natively - so if you want to develop your project with Python, you will probably want a Python framework to stay on the server side.

However, there are a few projects out there which can translate a Python-like language to javascript, either at build time, or on the client side.

The key to these projects getting as powerfull as other popular Javascript libraries is just to get enough users - as they are, they are usable, but lacking some features, and with some bugs. This however, canony be fixed with more and more people using them.

For a basic script, using Python "import" features, having the "def" function definition,
classes, lists and dictionaries of Python, and enough interactivity with the HTML document,
I'd suggest using [Brython](http://brython.info)